# App icon not showing up on iPhone - Xcode 9.1 or 10 or 10 Beta

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, icons, beta

I'm having a problem getting my app icon to show on device and in simulator. I have tried various ways suggested on stack overflow already. These include:

1.changing the Xcode version from 9.1 through to 10 latest beta 
2.removing alpha channel on icon png's 
3.changing the colour profile of the png to sRGB IEC61966-2.1

Is anyone else experiencing this issue.

[Bottom right, quiz app no icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z50NP.jpg)

[Colour profile changed to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xwUq.png)

Comment: Are you sure the image Asset is completed in your project? Try to use also Xcode 10.0 final release

Comment: Delete the app and install it again...it may solve your problem.

Comment: Check if your dimensions are correct. For ex: 2x of 20pt will be 40x40pixels